# Aligning four CAEmitterLayer() on each side of view, pointing inward

Tags: swift, particle-system, caemitterlayer, caemittercell

I'm working on adding 4 `CAEmitterLayers` to a subview. Each `CAEmitterLayer` is a line, and will be positioned on each side. Rotation will be controlled via `CGAffineTransform`

**My problem:**

I can't get the .Left and .Right emitterPosition to properly line up with the left and right side of the view

**Here's my progress:**

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.layer.cornerRadius = GlobalConstants.smallCornerRadius
    createParticles(direction: .Up)
    createParticles(direction: .Down)
    createParticles(direction: .Left)
    createParticles(direction: .Right)
}

enum EmitTo {
    case Up
    case Down
    case Left
    case Right
}

func createParticles(direction: EmitTo) {
    self.layoutSubviews()
    let particleEmitter = CAEmitterLayer()
    particleEmitter.position = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.midX, y: self.bounds.midY)
    particleEmitter.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.size.width, height: self.bounds.size.height)
    
    
    if direction == .Up {
        particleEmitter.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 0))
    } else if (direction == .Down) {
        particleEmitter.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi))
    } else if (direction == .Left) {
        particleEmitter.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi / 2))
    } else if (direction == .Right) {
        particleEmitter.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -.pi / 2))
    }
    
    if direction == .Up || direction == .Down {
        particleEmitter.emitterPosition = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: 0)
    }
    if direction == .Left {
        particleEmitter.emitterPosition = CGPoint(x: self.frame.height / 2, y: self.frame.height)
    }
    if direction == .Right {
        particleEmitter.emitterPosition = CGPoint(x: self.frame.height / 2, y: -50)
    }
    
    
    particleEmitter.emitterSize = self.bounds.size
    particleEmitter.emitterShape = CAEmitterLayerEmitterShape.line
    particleEmitter.zPosition = 1
    
    let triangle = makeEmitterCell(direction: direction)
    particleEmitter.emitterCells = [triangle]

    self.layer.addSublayer(particleEmitter)
}

func makeEmitterCell(direction: EmitTo) -> CAEmitterCell {
    let cell = CAEmitterCell()
    cell.birthRate = 25
    cell.lifetime = 3
    cell.lifetimeRange = 0
    cell.velocity = 10
    cell.velocityRange = 5
    cell.emissionLongitude = .pi
    
    cell.spin = 2
    cell.spinRange = 3
    cell.scale = 0.4
    cell.scaleRange = 0.6
    cell.scaleSpeed = -0.10

    cell.contents = UIImage(named: "greenTriangle")?.cgImage
    return cell
}
```

**What's happening:**

[image: gif animation of particle system]

**My question**

How can I get the `.Left` and `.Right` `CAEmitterLayer` to properly align with the left side and right side of the gray view?

**Green Triangle Image:**

[image: Green Triangle Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach to try to use `CGAffineTransform` is promising because a line emitter is a horizontal line that has only a width dimension. By rotating it, you can have it emit from the left or right.

However you need to use emitter bounds with the view height as width and the view width as height.

```
particleEmitter.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.size.height, height: bounds.size.width)
```

Accordingly, one sets the width of the emitterSize to the height of the view:

```
particleEmitter.emitterSize = CGSize(width: bounds.size.height, height: 0)
```

The emitter position must be adjusted in the same way.

Why is this so? Take a look at the following illustration with an emission from the top:

[image: rotation illustration]

If you rotate the layer by 90 degrees you would only cover a small area in the middle. Also the emissions would not be visible, because they would be to much outside to the left.

The difference between having the emitter on the left or the right is just a call to `setAffineTransform` with either `-.pi / 2` or  `.pi / 2`.

The emitters from top and bottom of course should get the normal bounds, they only need to be rotated as you do in your question.

**Hints**

In your `createParticles` method you call `self.layoutSubviews()`. That should be avoided.

Apple docs explicitly state:

> You should not call this method directly.

see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews.

Instead you could override `layoutSubviews` and call your `createParticles` methods from there. Make sure to remove any previously created emitter layers by removing them.

One small thing: Swift switch cases start with a lowercase letter by convention.

**Code**

A complete example to help you get started might then look something like this:

```
import UIKit

class EmitterView: UIView {
    
    private var emitters = [CAEmitterLayer]()
    
    enum EmitTo {
        case up
        case down
        case left
        case right
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        emitters.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperlayer() }
        emitters.removeAll()
        createParticles(direction: .up)
        createParticles(direction: .down)
        createParticles(direction: .left)
        createParticles(direction: .right)
    }
    
    func createParticles(direction: EmitTo) {
        let particleEmitter = CAEmitterLayer()
        emitters.append(particleEmitter)
        particleEmitter.position = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        particleEmitter.emitterShape = .line

        switch direction {
        case .up, .down:
            particleEmitter.bounds = self.bounds
            particleEmitter.emitterPosition = CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width / 2, y: 0)
            particleEmitter.emitterSize = CGSize(width: bounds.size.width, height: 0)
            if direction == .up {
                particleEmitter.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -.pi))
            }
        case .left, .right:
            particleEmitter.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.size.height, height: bounds.size.width)
            particleEmitter.emitterPosition = CGPoint(x: bounds.height / 2, y: 0)
            particleEmitter.emitterSize = CGSize(width: bounds.size.height, height: 0)
            let rotationAngle: CGFloat = direction == EmitTo.left ?  -.pi / 2 : .pi / 2
            particleEmitter.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: rotationAngle))
        }
        particleEmitter.emitterCells = [makeEmitterCell()]
        
        layer.addSublayer( particleEmitter)
    }
    
    func makeEmitterCell() -> CAEmitterCell {
        let cell = CAEmitterCell()
        cell.birthRate = 25
        cell.lifetime = 3
        cell.lifetimeRange = 0
        cell.velocity = 10
        cell.velocityRange = 5
        cell.emissionLongitude = .pi
        
        cell.spin = 2
        cell.spinRange = 3
        cell.scale = 0.4
        cell.scaleRange = 0.6
        cell.scaleSpeed = -0.10
        
        cell.contents = UIImage(named: "greenTriangle")?.cgImage
        return cell
    }
}
```

**Test**

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank you very much! Your explanations made perfect sense, and your rotation illustration was helpful. Question - rather than looping the emitters to remove them and re-add them in `layoutSubviews`, could I just do something like `var addedParticles = false`  `if !addedParticles { // Create Particles addedParticles = true }` ? I will award the bounty once I'm able to.

Comment: `layoutSubviews` is called when the view is resized. Since several emitter settings (emitterPosition, emitterSize etc.) depend on the view size (bounds), it is not enough to set them up only once based on a boolean variable. Of course, if you don't want to remove and re-add them, you can set them in instance variables and make the emitter adjustments accordingly when `layoutSubview` is called. A simple test case for this is rotating the device.